# PCRE regexp: multiple capture groups, repeated

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'd like to transform a string, containing a "simple" PHP array, into an array itself (without using `eval()`).

I ended up with the regexp below, which works fine but captures only the last "group" of `'attr' => 'val'`. I get this can be solved by using *non-capturing* groups, but I wasn't able to adapt it to my needs.

```
^\[["'](?P<route>[\w\/]+)["'](,\s*["'](?P<paramname>[\w]+)["']\s*=>\s*["']?(?P<paramval>[\w]+)?["']?){0,}
```

Some patterns I'd like to match:

```php
['conrtroller/action']
['conrtroller/action', 'param' => 1]
['conrtroller/action','param' => 1]
['conrtroller/action','param' => '1']
['conrtroller/action','param' => '1','param2' => 2]
```

All those works except the last one, that will return only `'param2' => 2`.

Best would be to only return named groups, so I don't have to deal with skipping unnecessary items.

The final goal is to construct a PHP array by looping the found matches of `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/seZSK5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression with `preg_match_all`:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^\[["'](?P<route>[\w\/]+)["'])(?:,\s*["'](?P<paramname>\w+)["']\s*=>\s*["']?(?P<paramval>\w+)?["']?|)(?=.*?])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSV2gY/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^\[["'](?P<route>[\w\/]+)["'])` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or `^\[["'](?P<route>[\w\/]+)["']`: start of string, `[`, `'` or `"`, then one or more word or `/` chars captured into Group "route", and then a `"` or `'` char
- `(?:,\s*["'](?P<paramname>\w+)["']\s*=>\s*["']?(?P<paramval>\w+)?["']?|)`  - a non-capturing group that either matches an empty string (see `|)` at the end) or a comma, zero or more whitespaces, `"` or `'`, one or more word chars captured into Group "paramname", `"` or `'`, a `=>` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, an optional `'` or `"`, one or more word chars captured into an optional Group "paramval", and then an optional `'` or `"`
- `(?=.*?])` - there must be a `]` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible.

Here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/UlZXDn):

```php
<?php

$strs= ["['conrtroller/action']", "['conrtroller/action', 'param' => 1]", "['conrtroller/action','param' => 1]", "['conrtroller/action','param' => '1']", "['conrtroller/action','param' => '1','param2' => 2]"];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|^\[["\'](?P<route>[\w\/]+)["\'])(?:,\s*["\'](?P<paramname>\w+)["\']\s*=>\s*["\']?(?P<paramval>\w+)?["\']?|)(?=.*?])~', $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
        //print_r($matches);
        foreach ($matches as $m) {
            if (!empty($m["route"])) { echo "---- New string match ---\n" . $m["route"] . PHP_EOL; }
            if (!empty($m["paramname"])) { echo "- " . $m["paramname"] . PHP_EOL; }
            if (!empty($m["paramval"])) { echo  "- " . $m["paramval"] . PHP_EOL; }
        }
    }
}
```

yielding

```
---- New string match ---
conrtroller/action
---- New string match ---
conrtroller/action
- param
- 1
---- New string match ---
conrtroller/action
- param
- 1
---- New string match ---
conrtroller/action
- param
- 1
---- New string match ---
conrtroller/action
- param
- 1
- param2
- 2
```

Comment: Wow, super fast, thanks. Mind explaining a little bit?

Comment: @Maxxer I added the pattern description. If you need more details please let know.

Comment: Like a mini tutorial, always a pleasure.